# How to access data within json using nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to access data within a json file using nodeJS

When I run this I get the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'postcode' of undefined`. Any Suggestions?

```js
{
    "apiName": "Restaurants",
    "pages": [
        {
            "pageUrl": "https://url",
            "results": [
                {
                    "address": "3F Belvedere Road Coutry Hall, London, SE17GQ",
                    "phone": "+442076339309",
                    "name": "Name",
                    "postcode": "SE17GQ"
                }
            ]
        }    
    ]
}

var myData = require('./jsonFile.json');

console.log(myData.pages.result.postcode);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to access data as below:

```
console.log(myData.pages[0].results[0].postcode);
```

The value in the bracket is the index of element to access.
Its the common singular/plural trap, I fall for it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

In your json, `pages` & `results` are arrays. You need to access these with an index. Also, you have a typo in the name.

Try this:

```
console.log(myData.pages[0].results[0].postcode);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will gave you correct answer.

```
console.log(myData.pages[0].results[0].postcode);
```